# Show real object hierarchy in gdb/Eclipse CDT debug watch by pointer

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

MSVS has a nice feature, when watching a pointer to an interface, it shows the real object. E.g.

```
struct IIntf1 {}
struct IIntf2 {}
class CIntf1: public IIntf1 {}
class CIntf2: public IIntf2, public CIntf1 {}
IIntf1 *p = new CIntf2();
```

MSVS will show that p is really CIntf2, which is IIntf1 and all its members, it will even show multiple and nested classes there (that p is C/IIntf1 and so on).

Is there something like this for gdb and/or Eclipse CDT under Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Try `set print object on` in gdb.  (You might also try `set print pretty` if you want the printed objects to have more structure.)